# UV Mapping a simple cube only shows 2 sides textured

Tags: texturing, uv

I can only get two sides of a simple cube to show the UV Map in Blender properly. Here are my steps:

- I add a simple cube (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > cube)
- In edit mode, I add seams to unwrap like a cross (see pic below)
- <kbd>A</kbd> (select all), <kbd>U</kbd> > *Unwrap*
- In UV Editor, create new blank image, draw numbers on it with the paint function
- in 3D View Editor, change to "Texture view".

All normals of the faces show correctly to the outside (blue lines in picture). I can flip the normals of the faces and then I can see the numbers, but slightly darker than the first two. Also, I can only do that trick on 3 of the incorrect faces. The last face, whichever one it is, flips the normals but won't show the UV map.

I have also tried different UV map textures and pictures (such as the built-in UV- or Color-grid)

How can I unwrap with seams so that I don't even need to consider flipping already correct normals?
[image: 3D View and UV-Map Editor screenshot]

Comment: Did you add a material first? You never mentioned that important step.

Comment: Actually, adding material or not did not make any difference. To my understanding I use either a texture (here via UV map) OR a Blender material. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Actually, it's not going to give you predictable results unless you DO add a material first. It might work at times without one, but it will result in problems..... like the one you're having!

Comment: Sorry, I agree if I want to render and I played more with it. Thanks. My aim is to just create a UV map for use in another context, not for rendering. Hence, I was not concerned with the material. But thank you for the help.

Comment: Even when not rendering, it can create problems. The proper process is to add a material before adding a texture. There is a reason for that. Read the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like a problem with your lighting: texture viewport mode can do some strange things with your lighting. Try adding a sun lamp illuminating the other side, or switching to rendered or material view with the texture applied in the material. I apologize if I am not answering your question appropriately (I am only going off of your text because my browser won't show your picture). Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed the lighting. I did not expect it to make such a difference since I thought that the 3D View while editing was not influenced by the lights in the scene. I thought they were relevant for rendering only.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lighting issue. You can fix it by going to Properties Region window (press 'N')> Shading > **Shaderless**.

The following is the cube before making it shaderless:
[image]

After checkmarking 'Shaderless':
[image]